# what's wrong with this code for truncation number m=9?

Tags: plotting, numerical-value

I have a puzzling problem over the following mathematica code I program to solve some problem. I believe the two plots as defined are identical, but it is only identical when mm<9 and when m is greater than 9, these two plots are not identical(which is quite confusing and unexpected before). At mm=8, the two plots are identical, but at mm=9, the two plots are quite different in scale. Furthermore, if R is changed from  exact 1 to numerical 1.0, the two plots become identical again. What happens here? I can not figure it out after hours. Could any one check and help ?
Here is the description on the problem:
For mm=9, the two plots are https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkVM1.png.
But for mm=8, the two plots are https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI36z.png.
And furthermore if R=1 is changed to R=1.0 and then at mm=9, the two plots are identical again:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF21O.png.
I am desperate about it. So any one can hint on this would be greatly appreciated.

Some comments show that the plots are correct by mm=9 in mma 12. I used mma version 9.0, here is the screenshot of the evaluation(I deleted some "print" commands) in my mma 9.0:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgfZe.png.

I am still confused about it. Can any one using mma 9.0 try this?

```
    Clear["Global`*"];
    w[0] = b;
    EEeII = 1 + \[Alpha] (1 - s/Pi)^\[Beta]; R = 1; \[Alpha] = 10; \[Beta] = 4;
    wd1 = Integrate[-w[0] - p R^3 w[0] EEeII + CC R^2 EEeII, {s, 0, s}];
    mm=9;
    w[1] = Integrate[wd1, {s, 0, s}]
    For[ii = 2, ii <= mm, ii++, 
     w[ii] = Integrate[
        Integrate[-w[ii - 1] - p R^3 w[ii - 1] EEeII, {s, 0, s}], {s, 0, 
         s}] // Expand;
     Print[ii];]
    Summ = Sum[w[ii], {ii, 0, mm}];
    H1 = D[Summ, s] /. s -> Pi;
    H2 = Integrate[Summ, {s, 0, Pi}];
    DetDet = Det[D[{H1, H2}, {{b, CC}}]]
    Plot[Det[D[{H1, H2}, {{b, CC}}]], {p, 0, 3}]
    Plot[DetDet, {p, 0, 3}]
```

Comment: I have tried your code and got identical results for `mm=9`and `R=1`

Comment: MMA version 12.3.0 on WIndows 10: Plots are identical with m==9. But b,pCC, are not defined.

Comment: @yarchik，I used mma version 9. The result is different.

Comment: @yarchik I have pasted our evaluation in mma 9 in the above description as screenshot.

Comment: @DanielHuber, H1,H2 are linear in b,CC and thus by taking Det[D[{H1, H2}, {{b, CC}}]], b,CC vanish. In my evaluation pasted as screenshot in mma 9.0, the results are different(see above). Is this related to version of mma. I am confused.

Comment: In my case both plots look the same, y-range approx. -50..10

Comment: I also checked it in mma version 12.3. Indeed the results are identical. So maybe the problem in mma version 9 has been fixed in mma version 12.3.